# VBA: Copying Pivot Table but remove data link, while keeping Pivot Table functionality

Tags: vba, excel, pivot-table

**Problem:** I am trying to copy a Pivot Table (linked to data) and Paste that Pivot Table in a new workbook. All the while keeping the functionality of the Pivot Table intact, but have the data link be removed as the data of the new Pivot Table must remain static.

My code copies correctly and breaks the link, but the new Pivot Table has no functionality. Which makes sense, but I can't find a solution to this problem. The data link must be removed as I don't want the possibility of the static table being refreshed. This is for the purpose of keeping monthly statements.

```
Private Sub Auto_Open()
  'variables
  Dim excelDocPath As String, newfilePath As String, newfileName As String, NewBook As Workbook, MasterBook As Workbook, i As Integer

  'initialize strings
  excelDocPath = ActiveWorkbook.Path & "\FILE_1.xlsx"
  newfilePath = ActiveWorkbook.Path & "\FOLDER\"

  'refresh linked master excel workbook
  Set MasterBook = Application.Workbooks.Open(excelDocPath, UpdateLinks:=True, ReadOnly:=False) 'create reference to master excel workbook
  MasterBook.Worksheets("Sheet1").PivotTables("PivotTable").PivotCache.Refresh 'refresh the pivot table source link
  MasterBook.RefreshAll 'refresh all links
  MasterBook.Save 'save changes
  MasterBook.Close 'close workbook

  'initialize new file name with current date
  newfileName = "FILENAME (" & Replace(Date, "/", "-") & ").xlsx"

  'copy master doc and save as newfileName
  FSO.CopyFile excelDocPath, newfilePath & newfileName 'copy temple file and rename accordingly

  Set NewBook = Application.Workbooks.Open(newfilePath & newfileName, UpdateLinks:=xlUpdateLinksNever, ReadOnly:=False) 'make reference to new workbook
  NewBook.Activate 'make workbook the active workbook

  'loop through workbook connections and delete all
  For i = ActiveWorkbook.Connections.Count To 1 Step -1
    ActiveWorkbook.Connections.Item(i).Delete
  Next

  NewBook.Save 'save changes
  NewBook.Close 'close new workbook
End Sub
```

Comment: The default behaviour of a pivot table is to copy it's source data when the table is copied (copy a workshhet with a PT to a new book and double click a cell intersection to see what I mean)... so where is the original source for you data? I'm guessing it's not in the workbook you copy?

Comment: I am using a .iqy file as my original source for my data. That file is linked to the master Pivot Table.

Comment: I'd probably go with copying the source to the new workbook and rebuilding the PT, but donno, maybe there's a more native way someone can come up with.